# Most efficient approach to read excel file and display in tabular format in a JSP

Tags: excel, angular, jsp

I have a web application written in JSP servlets and the requirement is to read excel and display in tabular format in JSP page. While I do understand that the same can be achieved using the Apache POI API and the rows can be iterated through in the JSP via scriptlets, I understand that may not be the best approach

I have read some features of Angular such as directives can be used in JSPs, am a newbie in Angular and have a basic knowledge only, so just wondering if I could leverage any Angular features for reading this excel file and displaying in JSP via Angular

Options I could think of 
1) some Jquery plugin?
2) Javascript
3) Angular mix with JSP

The working code I have reads through an excel through Apache POI and doesn't look like the most efficient approach.

Please advise.

Comment: A colleague just mentioned reading excel sheet into a Guava table, made a lot of sense if you do not want to iterate through multiple times